# I use celery beat worker to create new process that use billiard and set daemonic, but daemonic is not working

Tags: celery

billiard version 3.5.0.5
celery 4.0.2

**Steps to reproduce**

I want control long time beat task. like if a task not finish, not run a new process.

```
def lock_beat_task(gap_time, flush_time):

    def decorate(func):
        """
       Celery timing task solves the problem that the previous task is executed again when it is not executed.
       problem: Celery is similar to crontab, it will be scheduled regularly, regardless of whether the previous task is executed or not.
       achieve: With the help of the cache, the key is the class name, and each time the schedule is checked, it is checked whether it is executed before, and the key is deleted after the execution.
        :param func:
        :return:
        """

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            key_name = func.__name__

            logger.info('++++++++{} enter +++++++.'.format(key_name))
            monitor = BeatWokerMonitor(key_name, gap_time, flush_time)
            mo_process = monitor.monitor()
            if mo_process:
                try:
                    logger.info('++++++++{} is running.++++++++'.format(key_name))
                    func(*args, **kwargs)
                    logger.info('{} is graceful end.'.format(key_name))
                except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                    monitor.logger.info('{} KeyboardInterrupt reset succ'.format(key_name))
                finally:
                    monitor.reset()
                    # mo_process.join()
            else:
                logger.info('{} is running or gap time is not over.'.format(key_name))
            logger.info('{} is end!---.'.format(key_name))
        return wrapper
    return decorate

class BeatWokerMonitor(object):
    """
      Used to maintain/monitor the health status of the beat workerCall beat_worker_shoud_run. 

      If there is no key_name in redis, or the time difference between the current time and key_name is 
      greater than gap_time, create a monitor daemon.

      This daemon is responsible for refreshing the time in key_name at a fixed 
      time.Beat_worker_shoud_run returns true(should run)。 Otherwise return None
    """
    def __init__(self, key_name, gap_time, flush_time):
        """
        秒级时间
        :param key_name:
        :param gap_time:
        :param flush_time:
        """
        self.key_name = key_name
        self.gap_time = gap_time
        self.flush_time = flush_time
        self.db_redis = get_redis_conn(11)

    def start_monitor(self):
        flush_key_process = Process(target=self.flush_redis_key_gap_time, name='{}_monitor'.format(self.key_name), daemon=True)
        flush_key_process.start()

        return flush_key_process

    def monitor(self):
        rd_key_value = self.get_float_rd_key_value()
        if not rd_key_value:
            v = time.time()
            self.db_redis.set(self.key_name, v)
            return self.start_monitor()

        if time.time() - rd_key_value > self.gap_time:
            return self.start_monitor()

    def get_float_rd_key_value(self):
        value = self.db_redis.get(self.key_name)
        if value:
            return float(value)
        else:
            return 0

    def flush_redis_key_gap_time(self):
        old_time = self.get_float_rd_key_value()
        self.logger.info('{} start flush, now is {}'.format(self.key_name, old_time))
        while 1:
            if time.time() - old_time > self.flush_time:
                now = time.time()
                self.db_redis.set(self.key_name, now)
                old_time = now
                self.logger.info('{} monitor flush time {}'.format(self.key_name, now))

            else:
                self.logger.info('{} not flush {} , {}'.format(self.key_name, time.time() - old_time, self.flush_time))

    def reset(self):
        self.db_redis.delete(self.key_name)
```

and task code. you can write some short time task to test .

```
@app.task
@lock_beat_task(5*60, 10*3)
@send_update_msg("update")
def beat_update_all():
    """

    :return:
    """
    from crontab.update import EAllTicket
    eall = EAllTicket()
    send_task_nums = eall.run()
    return send_task_nums
```

**Expected behavior**

want background run, so can not use multiprocessing to create child process.
use billiard instead
want beat_update_all() finished and monitor process will kill itself.

**Actual behavior**

beat_update_all() finished and monitor process is still running.